# How do I get started with importing serviceM8 (from a REST API ) Invoices to a Windows application

Tags: .net, json, rest

I have a need to integrate a window application ( accounting - ERP ) with ServiceM8  ( has a REST API ) see url below.
all I need is to read Invoice details on ServiceM8 when an Invoice is create on it and get the data in a XML or similar format down to a windows server for later processing by another application.

Can this be done using a .Net windows application ?
if so where do I start ? what steps should I follow ?

The URL to the ServiceM8 api is below.
http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/the-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only need to read from the API (i.e. you're only doing a one-way sync), there are three important things you'll need to do

1. Make a HTTP request to the ServiceM8 API
2. Include the correct authentication in that request
3. Parse the response to something you can understand

**HTTP Request**

Create an instance of System.Net.HTTPWebRequest and call GetResponse(). There is a guide on how to do this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/vendor.json")
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();    
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Without authentication, this will just give you a 401 Unauthorized.

**Authentication**

ServiceM8 accepts HTTP Basic auth for private applications. If you're making a public application (distributed to many customers) you can use OAuth2 which I won't cover.

HTTP Basic auth is just a matter of including the appropriate header when you make your HTTP request. The Wiki article is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

So you need to add your header before calling GetResponse().

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic myauthstring");
```

Where *myauthstring* is the base64-encoded username:password as described in the Wikipedia link above. I think there may be a method to do this built into the WebRequest class, rather than manually creating the HTTP header, but I have not used .NET in a while so you'll have to look it up.

**Parse the response**

ServiceM8 will respond with JSON-formatted data, not XML. You can use a library like JSON.NET (https://json.codeplex.com/) to interpret this and do what you need to do.

**Endpoints**

If you are importing invoices from ServiceM8 into an accounting system, the endpoints you will want to look at are:

Jobs: invoices and jobs are equivalent in ServiceM8. One job results in one invoice. You will want to look at jobs with status="Completed".

JobMaterials: these are the line items on the invoice

JobContacts: Site and Billing contact details for the job

These are all documented at http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/reference/